# Difference between these python visitor design pattern implementation choices?

Tags: python, design-patterns, visitor-pattern, design-principles, first-class-functions

I was reading the ***implementing_the_visitor_pattern_without_recursion*** from ***Python Cookbook, Third Edition***

[The implementation with additional `Visit` Class](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/8/implementing_the_visitor_pattern_without_recursion/example3.py)  fix the defect in [the one without it](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/8/implementing_the_visitor_pattern_without_recursion/node.py) as it claims.

> “One potential danger of this recipe concerns the distinction between
>   yielding Node and non-Node values. In the implementation, all Node
>   instances are automatically traversed. This means that you can’t use a
>   Node as a return value to be propagated. In practice, this may not
>   matter. However, if it does, you might need to adapt the algorithm
>   slightly. For example, possibly by introducing another class into the
>   mix, like this:”
>
> Excerpt From: David Beazley. “Python Cookbook.” iBooks.

**Here are the questions:**
1: Under what circumstance does this *potential danger* would happen
2: How does the additional `Visit` Class come to fix it?

(I don't understand and as far as I can see the `Visit` class is merely a useless wrapper on the `node`)
(May be just because I am stupid, could someone explain it to me in more detail and with some code probably? Thanx for reading)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my senses, wrapping a `Visit` class,
help that the visitor could actually return the final result as a whole Node
instead of its(the Node) unfolding result, giving us an option to abort the visiting process if demand it.